# Display RAW RGB byte array in PictureBox in WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, rgb, picturebox

I have an .rgb file that I attached. It is a valid rgb file that I verified through other software. As far as I understand this is a raw RGB data file.

I need to load the file into byte[] and display it in PictureBox.
From all my searches here I came to this solution that seems correct and that works for others. Unfortunately it displays nothing for me:

```
                    string imgPath = Path.Combine(mInstallPath, "squirrel-720x576x50.rgb\\squirrel-720x576x50.rgb");
                byte[] imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(imgPath); 

                using (var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
                {
                    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                                                    bmp.Width,
                                                                    bmp.Height),
                                                                    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                                                    bmp.PixelFormat);
                    Marshal.Copy(imageData, 0, bmpData.Scan0, width * height * 3);//imageData.Length);
                    //bmpSource.CopyPixels((Int32Rect.Empty, bmpData.Scan0, bmpData.Height * bmpData.Stride, bmpData.Stride);
                    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                    pictureBox.Image = bmp;
                }
```

Any ideas why nothing is displayed in my pictureBox ?

Comment: Because you are `using` the `bitmap`, it gets disposed at the end of the scope -> use a class-level variable instead.

Comment: Many thanks, I am not sure how I did not see it before...

Comment: Thank you for asking this. Hope still active? Sorry but I could not follow the actual final answer. What should be the change as per Aybe? Really appreciate it to know how can this be done for a large (75mb) .rgb file. When I view my raw rgb file in YUV Toolkit it has multiple frames. But I want to view as a gray scale image in picturebox, similar to your code and requirement.